# CURL script to powershell

Tags: json, powershell, curl

I am trying to convert curl to powershell with Invoke-RestMethod for onesignal push

the script that is used for onesignal:

```
curl --include \
     --request POST \
     --header "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" \
     --header "Authorization: Basic YOUR_REST_API_KEY" \
     --data-binary "{\"app_id\": \"YOUR_APP_ID\",
\"contents\": {\"en\": \"English Message\"},
\"included_segments\": [\"Subscribed Users\"]}" \
     https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications
```

I have tried with following example which I was using for pushover but without success.

```
   $uri = "https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications"
      $parameters = @{
        app_id = 'YOUR_APP_ID'
        contents = "en: English Message"
        included_segments = 'Subscribed Users'
        data = 'foo:bar'
      }
      $parameters | Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Post
```

I have used this powershell script for pushover which worked fine, but now I want to move to onesignal and I have problems with where/how to put rest api key inside with already using app_id to push messages forward to users.

The code is snatched from: https://documentation.onesignal.com/v5.0/reference#section-example-code-create-notification

I hope that someone can assist me with this problem.

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following

```
$basicAuth = "Basic REST_API_KEY";
$headers = @{ Authorization = $basicAuth };
$uri = "https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications";
$body = @{ app_id = 'YOUR_APP_ID'; contents = @{ en = 'English Message' }; included_segments = @('Subscribed Users'); data = @{ foo = 'bar' }} | ConvertTo-Json;

Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $uri -Headers $headers -ContentType "application/json; charset=utf-8" -Body ([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($body));
```

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea how this endpoint works but it should work something like this:

```
$key = "Basic RESTAPIKEY"
$headers = @{}
$headers.Add("Authorization",$Key)
$headers.Add("Content-Type","application/json; charset=utf-8")

$uri = "https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications"
$parameters = @{
    app_id = 'YOUR_APP_ID'
    contents = "en: English Message"
    included_segments = 'Subscribed Users'
    data = 'foo:bar'
} | ConvertTo-Json

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Post -Headers $headers -Body ([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($parameters)) -ContentType "application/json"
```

If the data-binary part is sent with PowerShell you could also use the -InFile parameter from Invoke-RestMethod.

If just read a little at the link you posted and think the body part should be like the following:

```
$parameters = @{
    app_id = "5eb5a37e-b458-11e3-ac11-000c2940e62c"
    included_segments = "Array of active users"
    data = @{
        foo = "bar"
    }
    contents = @{
        en = "English Message"
    }
} | ConvertTo-JSON
```

Comment: Well it should be something similar to this? 
$headers = "Authorization: Basic xxxxxxxx REST API KEY xxxxxxxx"
$uri = "https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications"
$parameters = @{
    app_id = "xxxxxxxxx ONESIGNAL APP ID xxxxxxxxxx"
    included_segments = "All"
    data = @{
        foo = "bar"
    }
    contents = @{
        en = "English Message"
    }
} | ConvertTo-JSON

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Post -Headers $headers -Body $parameters -ContentType "application/json" but that doesnt work either, I get 2 keys from onesignal, one for rest api and one for app id.

Comment: This is how its done in python: import requests
import json

header = {"Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          "Authorization": "Basic NGEwMGZmMjItY2NkNy0xMWUzLTk5ZDUtMDAwYzI5NDBlNjJj"}

payload = {"app_id": "5eb5a37e-b458-11e3-ac11-000c2940e62c",
           "included_segments": ["Active Users"],
           "contents": {"en": "English Message"}}
 
req = requests.post("https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications", headers=header, data=json.dumps(payload))
 
print(req.status_code, req.reason)

Comment: I edited a few bits, maybe you could try again with the edited key, body and headers..

Comment: Invoke-RestMethod : The 'Content-Type' header must be modified using the appropriate property or method.
Parameter name: name
At line:1 char:1
+ Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Post -Headers $headers -Body ([System.Text.E ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Invoke-RestMethod], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand